# Incomplete response from MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to get some information using a UNION query by joining multiple tables. The issue is that there might not be any data in some of the tables that are being joined. So i tried to check using if loops if the rows have data, then assign the data otherwise keep the objects null. This is my code:

```js
const guardProfile = (req, res) => {
  const guardProfile = {};
  const { id } = req.params; // guard ID
  try {
    let isAdmin = 0;
    if (isAdmin === 0) {
      connection.query(
        `SELECT 'guard' AS tablename, guard.* FROM guard WHERE guardID=${id}
        UNION
        SELECT 'guardaddress' AS tablename, guardaddress.*, Null as col6, Null as col7, Null as col8, Null as col9, Null as col10, Null as col11, Null as col12, Null as col13, Null as col14, Null as col15, Null as col16 FROM guardaddress WHERE fk_guard=${id}
        UNION
        SELECT 'document' as tablename, document.* FROM document WHERE fk_guard=${id}
        UNION
        SELECT 'otherdocs' AS tablename, otherdocs.*, Null as col5, Null as col6, Null as col7, Null as col8, Null as col9, Null as col10, Null as col11, Null as col12, Null as col13, Null as col14, Null as col15, Null as col16 FROM otherdocs WHERE fk_guard=${id}
        UNION
        SELECT 'bank' AS tablename, bank.*, Null as col8, Null as col9, Null as col10, Null as col11, Null as col12, Null as col13, Null as col14, Null as col15, Null as col16 FROM bank WHERE guard_id=${id}`,
        function (err, rows) {
          if (!err) {
              const guardToken = jwt.sign(
              {
                id: rows[0].guardID,
                isAdmin: rows[0].isAdmin,
                isGuard: rows[0].isGuard,
                isCompany: rows[0].isCompany,
              },
              SECRET,
              {
                expiresIn: "3d",
              }
            );
            
            let guard = null, address = null, documents = null, otherdocs = null, bank = null;
            rows.forEach(row => {
              switch (row.tablename) {
                case 'guard':
                  guard = {
                    guardID: row.guardID,
                    firstName: row.firstName,
                    middleName: row.middleName,
                    lastName: row.lastName,
                    email: row.email,
                    password: row.password,
                    phone: row.phone,
                    dob: row.dob,
                    gender: row.gender,
                    emergencyContact: row.emergencyContact,
                  };
                  break;
                case 'guardaddress':
                    address = {
                      state: rows[1].firstName,
                      city: rows[1].middleName,
                      postalCode: rows[1].lastName,
                    };
                    break;
                case 'document':
                    documents = {
                      four82: rows[2].firstName,
                      PCR: rows[2].middleName,
                      CPR: rows[2].lastName,
                      CrowdControl: rows[2].email,
                      License: rows[2].password,
                      Firearms: rows[2].phone,
                      FirstAid: rows[2].dob,
                      MediCare: rows[2].gender,
                      Passport: rows[2].status,
                      ResponsibleAlcohol: rows[2].isAdmin,
                      Visa: rows[2].admin_id,
                      WhiteCard: rows[2].address_id,
                      YellowCard: rows[2].isGuard,
                      WorkingWithChildren: rows[2].isCompany,
                    };
                    break;
                case 'otherdocs':
                    otherdocs = {
                      name: rows[3].firstName,
                      document: rows[3].middleName,
                    };
                    break;
                case 'bank':
                    bank = {
                      bankName: rows[4].firstName,
                      accountTitle: rows[4].middleName,
                      accountNo: rows[4].lastName,
                      bsb: rows[4].email,
                      abn: rows[4].password,
                    };
                    break;
                default:
                    guard = {};
                    address = {};
                    documents = {};
                    otherdocs = {};
                    bank = {};
                    break;
              }
            });
            
            res.status(201).json({
              status: true,
              message: "Got Guard Profile!",
              guardProfile: {
                  guard,
                  address,
                  documents,
                  otherDocs,
                  bank,
              },
              guardToken,
            });
          } else {
            res
              .status(404)
              .json({ success: false, message: "Guard Not Found!" });
          }
        }
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500);
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};
```

The issue now is, that even after placing the checks using if loops, i am still getting the `<h1>Incomplete response received from application</h1>` error from the page. If i try to request the data for a guard who has data for all the tables, it works fine, but if i try to request data for a guard that doesn't have all the data, i get the same error even though i put in the checks. I am not able to understand my mistake. Can someone point out the mistake for me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use string substitution to insert parameters in a query. Use a prepared statement with placeholders, and a parameter array.

Comment: Never ever do `guardID=${id}` in a query, especially not if the data can be externally controlled (`const { id } = req.params; // guard ID`). Use the capabilities of the mysql library to insert variables to the query that does the escaping correctly.

Comment: Are you sure each subquery will return a row? Your code assumes that if there are any results there will be 5 rows. Also, without an `ORDER BY` clause, you can't assume that the rows will be returned in the order of the subqueries.

Comment: Can there be duplication between the subqueries? `UNION` defaults to `UNION DISTINCT`, which removes duplicates. Use `UNION ALL` to prevent this.

Comment: @Barmar i am sure about which row index will output what kind of data, but the issue is that those rows can come in empty which breaks everything. I need a solution for that.

Comment: @t.niese that is a good suggestion, i will implement this. However, this still won't solve my issue which is to deal with empty rows.

Comment: A row can never be empty. All the rows returned by a query have to have the same length.

Comment: @Barmar i agree with your suggestion to not use string substitution as @t.niese also pointed out. I also have no issues with data duplication since i used ```UNION``` instead of ```UNION DISTINCT``` , but the issue of dealing with empty rows still remains. I need a solution to that.

Comment: `UNION` is the same a `UNION DISTINCT`, that's what I tried to tell you.

Comment: @Barmar as you can see in the query, i have added null columns to substitute for the number of columns in each row. As i mentioned, the code works perfectly if there is data available in all the tables. But it breaks if any table is empty. This is the issue i need a solution for. Thanks

Comment: You won't get an empty row, the row will be missing entirely if there's no match for the ID in that table. So you'll get less than 5 rows in the results.

Comment: @Barmar it works fine with ```UNION ALL``` also if there is data in all the tables. However it breaks if there's data missing in one of the tables.

Comment: The strange thing is that `Incomplete response received from the application` I'm not particularly sure why it is that error and not a timeout that I would expect. I would suggest to use an `try-catch` here `if (!err) { try { const guardToken = jwt.sign( .... res.status(201).json({ ... }) } catch (err) { res.status(502).json({ success: false, message: "Error" }); }` to check if an error happens in that block.

Comment: @Barmar yes exactly. the row will be completely missing since there won't be any data. So how do i handle this ?

Comment: @t.niese the ```Incomplete response received from the application``` error comes from the absence of rows from the ```SELECT``` queries. Since the rows are not available, the objects will not be assigned any value which results in the error. This is why i use if loops to check whether the row exists and has data. But this check doesn't seem to work. I need a workaround for this.

Comment: The problem I have is that `<h1>Incomplete response received from the application</h1>` to me is an nginx error.  `connection.query` should only throw if the connection for some reason is bad.  So any other error with the query would populate the `err` argument of the callback. So if you actually send a response in the callback it has to be JSON and not `html`. So an HTML error should only happen if you don't reach `res.status(201).json`, but then nginx should then respond with a Gateway timeout and not with an incomplete response.

Comment: was your problem resolved?

Comment: @Mohammedziou yes it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of the tables are missing data, that row will be completely missing from the results, it won't be an empty row. So testing `row[2].length` will not tell you if the third table had results, because that will be the result from the fourth table.

Add an identifying column to each subquery. Then you can tell which tables had data.

```
`SELECT 'guard' AS tablename, guard.* FROM guard WHERE guardID=${id}
UNION
SELECT 'guardaddress' AS tablename, guardaddress.*, Null as col6, Null as col7, Null as col8, Null as col9, Null as col10, Null as col11, Null as col12, Null as col13, Null as col14, Null as col15, Null as col16 FROM guardaddress WHERE fk_guard=${id}
UNION
SELECT 'document' as tablename, document.* FROM document WHERE fk_guard=${id}
UNION
SELECT 'otherdocs' AS tablename, otherdocs.*, Null as col5, Null as col6, Null as col7, Null as col8, Null as col9, Null as col10, Null as col11, Null as col12, Null as col13, Null as col14, Null as col15, Null as col16 FROM otherdocs WHERE fk_guard=${id}
UNION
SELECT 'bank' AS tablename, bank.*, Null as col8, Null as col9, Null as col10, Null as col11, Null as col12, Null as col13, Null as col14, Null as col15, Null as col16 FROM bank WHERE guard_id=${id}`,
```

Then loop through the rows, updating the appropriate variables.

```
let guard = null,
  address = null,
  documents = null,
  otherdocs = null,
  bank = null;
rows.forEach(row => {
  switch (row.tablename) {
    case 'guard':
      guard = {
        guardID: row.guardID,
        firstName: row.firstName,
        middleName: row.middleName,
        lastName: row.lastName,
        email: row.email,
        password: row.password,
        phone: row.phone,
        dob: row.dob,
        gender: row.gender,
        emergencyContact: row.emergencyContact,
      }
      break;
      // and similar for each other table name
  }
});
```

Comment: i tried this, but it seems that there is an issue with the query since i am not able to get any data in return. @Barmar

Comment: I've fixed the query. You can't use `*` after another column, you have to use `tablename.*`.

Comment: i tried it with the new query, however, it now gives the ```<h1>Incomplete response received from application</h1>``` error for all the guards.

Comment: Where does that message come from? I don't see it in the code.

Comment: i have updated the code in the question according to what i implemented following your answer. Please have a look @Barmar

Comment: Don't do that. Now my answer makes no sense, since no one can see what the original code was that I was fixing. You should add the new code, not remove the original code.

Comment: Get rid of the `default:` clause. That's overwriting the variables that were set on previous iterations.

Comment: If you want empty objects instead of `null` for the missing values, use that as the initial values rather than `{}`.

Comment: will the switch case work without a default case ?

Comment: Of course, why wouldn't it?

Comment: the issue still remains.

Comment: the query is fine, but now i do not have the results for any guard regardless. @Barmar

Comment: Try using `console.log(rows)` to see the full result of the query.